# Pandas averaging selected rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with some EPL stats. I have csv with all matches from one season in following format.

```
D           H                A           H_SC  A_SC H_ODDS  D_ODDS  A_ODDS...
11.05.2014  Norwich          Arsenal     0     2    5.00    4.00    1.73 
11.05.2014  Chelsea          Swansea     0     0    1.50    3.00    5.00
```

What I would like to do is for each match calculate average stats of teams from N previous matches. The result should look something like this.

```
D           H        A        H_SC         A_SC         H_ODDS  D_ODDS  A_ODDS...
11.05.2014  Norwich  Arsenal  avgNorwichSC avgArsenalSC 5.00    4.00    1.73
11.05.2014  Chelsea  Swansea  avgChelseaSC avgSwanseaSC 1.50    3.00    5.00
```

So the date, teams and odds remains untouched and other stats are replaced with average from N previous matches. EDIT: The matches from first N rounds should not be in final table  because there is not enough data to calculate averages.

The most tricky part for me is that the stats I am averaging have different prefix (H_ or A_) depending on where was the match played.

All I managed to do for now is to create dictionary, where key is club name and value is DataFrame containing all matches played by club.

```
D           H        A          H_SC  A_SC  H_ODDS  D_ODDS  A_ODDS...
11.05.2014  Norwich  Arsenal    0     2     5.00    4.00    1.73
04.05.2014  Arsenal  West Brom  1     0     1.40    5.25    8.00
```

I have also previously coded this without pandas, but I was not satisfied with the code and i would like to learn pandas :).

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! This cam to me to review as it is your first post.  Have you tried looking at the [`dataframe.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object? Maybe you can edit your question with what you've tried from that if so, if not - I'll answer.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Hello, I have actually came across groupby in the documentation/cookbook/tutorials. I felt like it is what I am looking for, however I was not able to apply it on my problem.

Comment: OK - just to clarify - the averages you want - are they score in previous N matches for team X *whether the matches were home or away*?

Comment: Yes. Also there are more stats in my table, all prefixed with H_/A_.

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to learn pandas, so I've given a few examples (tested with similar data) to get you going along the right track. It's a bit of an opinion, but I think finding the last `N` games is hard, so I'll initially assume / pretend you want to find averages over the whole table at first.  If finding "last N" is really import, I can add to the answer.  This should get you going with pandas and gropuby - I've left prints in so you can understand what's going on.

```
import pandas

EPL_df = pandas.DataFrame.from_csv('D:\\EPLstats.csv')
#Find most recent date for each team
EPL_df['D'] = pandas.to_datetime(EPL_df['D'])
homeGroup = EPL_df.groupby('H')
awayGroup = EPL_df.groupby('A')

#Following will give you dataframes, team against last game, home and away
homeLastGame = homeGroup['D'].max()
awayLastGame = awayGroup['D'].max()
teamLastGame = pandas.concat([homeLastGame, awayLastGame]).reset_index().groupby('index')['D'].max()
print teamLastGame

homeAveScore = homeGroup['H_SC'].mean()
awayAveScore = awayGroup['A_SC'].mean()
teamAveScore = (homeGroup['H_SC'].sum() + awayGroup['A_SC'].sum()) / (homeGroup['H_SC'].count() + awayGroup['A_SC'].count()) 

print teamAveScore
```

You now have average scores for each team along with their most recent match dates.  All you have to do now is select the relevant rows of the original dataframe using the most recent dates (i.e. eveything apart from the score columns) and then select from the average score dataframes using the team names from that row.

e.g.

```
recentRows = EPL_df.loc[EPL_df['D'] > pandas.to_datetime("2015/01/10")]

print recentRows

def insertAverages(s):
    a = teamAveScore[s['H']] 
    b = teamAveScore[s['A']]
    print a,b
    return pandas.Series(dict(H_AVSC=a, A_AVSC=b))

finalTable = pandas.concat([recentRows, recentRows.apply(insertAverages, axis = 1)], axis=1)

print finalTable
```

finalTable has your original odds etc for the most recent games with two extra columns (H_AVSC and A_AVSC) for the average scores of home and away teams involved in those matches

### Edit

Couple of gotchas

1. just noticed I didn't put a format string in `to_datetime()`.  For your dates - they look like UK format with dots so you should do

   ```
   EPL_df['D'] = pandas.to_datetime(EPL_df['D'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
   ```
2. You could use the minimum of the dates in `teamLastGame` instead of the hard coded `2015/01/10` in my example.
3. If you really need to replace column `H_SC` with `H_AVSC` in your `finalTable`, rather than add on the averages:

   ```
   newCols = recentRows.apply(insertAverages, axis = 1)

   recentRows['H_SC'] = newCols['H_AVSC']
   recentRows['A_SC'] = newCols['A_AVSC']

   print recentRows
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the groupby example, it is really illustrative. My approach would be creating separate dataframes with home and away game for each time and then summing and averaging, but this is of course much more effective. Unfortunately the "last N" restraint is really important and most bugging. I could proccess matches in loop (thats how I did it without pandas) but I read that is something I should try to avoid.

Comment: Yeah, in general you try to avoid looping through things in pandas if you can (because the looping is already optimised in the tool underneath).  I'll try to put in an example - the idea would be, concatenate homeGroup and awayGroup, sort by team then date, pick out first N for each team from that and then take the mean.  I'll post an example when back at desktop.

Comment: OK - this is trickier than I thought while avoiding just looping through the dictionary that you said you'd already got to in your OP and comment above.  I think there is a way with the `.apply` method, but I can't think of anything very pretty.  If I come up with something, I'll post it as an edit and leave a comment.